# Using flex for matching Python multiline strings with escaped characters

Tags: python, regex, flex-lexer, lex

I wonder how to match python multiple line comments with flex. And I meet some troubles, the following works fine on [Regexr](https://regexr.com/), but not recognized by flex, I don't know how to fix it.

```
"""[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|"{1,2}(?!"))[^"\\]*)*"""
```

Previously, I used:

```
["]{3}(\\["])*(["]{0,2}[^"](\\["])*)*["]{3}
```

which can detect comments like :

```
"""A\"""A"""
```

However, it cannot deal with multiple \, like

```
'''A\\\\'''A=B'''C'''
```

which recognize it as a whole not :

```
'''A\\\\'''  (comment)   
A=B     
'''C'''(comment)
```

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recognize Python long strings with a single regex. It's not pretty, but I believe it works:

```
["]{3}(["]{0,2}([^\\"]|\\(.|\n)))*["]{3}
```

This is fairly similar to your original regex, but it does not attempt to limit its backslash handling to `\"`, so that it can correctly identify `\\` as a backslashed character.

A possibly easier to read (but slightly slower) solution is to use start a start condition. Here I use `yymore()` to create a single token which does not include the `"""` delimiters, but production code would probably seek to interpret Python's various backslash escapes. (It is precisely this need which motivates the use of a start condition rather than trying to recognize the entire string with a single regex.)

```
%x SC_LONGSTRING
%%
["]{3}     BEGIN(SC_LONGSTRING);
<SC_LONGSTRING>{
  [^\\"]+  yymore();
  \\(.|\n) yymore();
  ["]["]?  yymore();
  ["]{3}   { BEGIN(INITIAL);
             yylval.str = malloc(yyleng - 2);
             memcpy(yylval.str, yytext, yyleng - 3);
             yylval.str[yyleng - 3] = 0;
             return TOKEN_STRING;
           }
}
```

Comment: I update your regex with unicode character support, would you please review it? `UCN (\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8})` and then `["]{3}(["]{0,2}([^\\"]|\\(.|\n)|{UCN}))*["]{3}`

Comment: @linrongbin: the regex already handles escape codes, and there is nothing special about UCNs which makes escape-handling more complicated. What it does not attempt to do is interpret escape codes; that would be impossible in a regex, although it is straight-forward in the start-condition model. Trying to validate UCNs in a regex creates more problems than it solves. What do you do with an invalid UCN (equally, with an invalid hex or letter escape)? You can't just stop recognising the literal at that point, which is what your modification would do.